# SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected 00923. 00000 - "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Tags: sql, oracle

Query

```
INSERT INTO cube_pivoted_rpt_metadata 
SELECT analytics_type, 
       scn_name, 
       column_name, 
       column_index, 
       base_scn_name, 
       AS_OF_DATE=To_date('20181031', 'yyyymmdd'), 
       dataset_Id=1, 
       scn_id, 
       sim_type 
FROM   cube_pivoted_rpt_metadata 
WHERE  dataset_id = 1 
       AND as_of_date = To_date('20181231', 'yyyymmdd') 
       AND analytics_type = 'CTC';
```

Comment: Did you mean `TO_DATE('20181031', 'yyyymmdd') as AS_OF_DATE`?  ... using `=` is not a valid syntax in the select

Answer (score 1):

Two errors, two objections:

- invalid use of `=` within `SELECT` (twice)
- you don't have to use constants (`TO_DATE`'s value and `1`) as you're selecting them from the table anyway
- **always** name all columns you're inserting into.

---

```
INSERT INTO cube_pivoted_rpt_metadata
  (analytics_type, scn_name, column_name, column_index,     --> put the whole 
   base_scn_name, as_of_date, dataset_id, scn_id, sim_type  --> column list here
  ) 
SELECT analytics_type, 
       scn_name, 
       column_name, 
       column_index, 
       base_scn_name, 
       as_of_date,        --> use column names as you've used them in WHERE  
       dataset_id,        --> clause anyway
       scn_id, 
       sim_type 
FROM   cube_pivoted_rpt_metadata 
WHERE  dataset_id = 1 
       AND as_of_date = To_date('20181231', 'yyyymmdd') 
       AND analytics_type = 'CTC';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use column alias instead of `=` sign in `select` list as below

```
INSERT INTO cube_pivoted_rpt_metadata 
SELECT analytics_type, 
       scn_name, 
       column_name, 
       column_index, 
       base_scn_name, 
       To_date('20181031', 'yyyymmdd') as AS_OF_DATE, 
       dataset_Id=1, 
       scn_id, 
       sim_type 
FROM   cube_pivoted_rpt_metadata 
WHERE  dataset_id = 1 
       AND as_of_date = To_date('20181231', 'yyyymmdd') 
       AND analytics_type = 'CTC';
```